# How allow only single bootstrap popover element

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) in conjunction with [bootstrap popovers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/) in my project. An ajax request is used to pull the info into the popover window. When many events are displayed, if the user quickly runs the mouse over the list of events the popover element appears but is not cleared. If the mouse is moved more slowly, everything works as expected where the popover appears on hover but disappears off hover.

After some testing, I think the problem is happening because of the delay introduced by the ajax event to pull the popover info. I have simulated this behavior in a js fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ehymel/8w5d0fx2/) using a javascript `setTimeout()` to simulate the ajax delay. Here is a pared-down version of the code:

```
$('td.test').hover(
  function() {
    let e = $(this);

    e.off('hover');

    // use setTimeout to simulate ajax request for popover content
    setTimeout(function() {
      e.popover({
        title: "Title",
        content: "<h1>Heading</h1><div>Some content</div>",
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true,
        boundary: 'viewport',
        container: 'body',
        sanitize: true,
        appendToBody: true,
      }).popover('show');
    }, 100);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).popover('hide');
  }
);

<div>
  <table>
   <tr>
      <td class="test">Lorum ipsum</td>
      <td class="test">Lorum ipsum</td>
      <td class="test">Lorum ipsum</td>
    <tr>
      <td class="test">Lorum ipsum</td>
      <td class="test">Lorum ipsum</td>
      <td class="test">Lorum ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="test">Lorum ipsum</td>
      <td class="test">Lorum ipsum</td>
      <td class="test">Lorum ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="test">Lorum ipsum</td>
      <td class="test">Lorum ipsum</td>
      <td class="test">Lorum ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I would like to allow only a single popover to appear at a time. I've tried to add something like `$('.test').popover('hide');` both before and after the ajax request, but this does not help (likely because the ajax function is too slow so the popover addition for a new hover happens before the previous popover has completed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this, so posting here for anyone else that runs into this problem.

Since the `popover()` function adds a `div` with class `popover` to the DOM, I just hide that element in then `done()` portion of the ajax call just before creating and showing the new popover. Here is my updated `hover()` with ajax call:

```
$(info.el).hover(
    function() {
        let e = $(this);
        e.off('hover');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/path/to/my/backend",
        }).done(function(data) {
            // these lines hide all previous popovers
            $('.popover').each(function() {
                $(this).popover('hide');
            });

            e.popover({
                title: "Title",
                content: data,
                placement: 'bottom',
                html: true,
                boundary: 'viewport',
                container: 'body',
                sanitize: true,
                appendToBody: true,
            }).popover('show')
        });
    },
    function() {
        $(this).popover('hide');
    }
);
```